# Node.js res.render() with Request not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to render an EJS template and pass in data to it with the node package Request. I have got this to work with no problem using node-fetch on my last project.

Here's a quick snippet of that:

```
const fetchCurrentWeather = (url, res) => {
   fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => res.render('pages/weather', {
        currentId: data.list
      }))
      .catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
         res.sendStatus(500);
      });
}
```

And this will render the EJS weather page template with the data from the API response.

With this latest project however, I am trying to use the Node Package Request to do the same thing and I am failing. Here's the code for that:

```
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const paramOptions = {
          url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search',
          method: 'GET',
          qs: {
            client_id: 'W033PDIYFI2TSAUO4L5ANUFOAUMZV32NUWNOF0NL0JS2E5W4',
            client_secret: 'SM1ZI11XOMPVMEGMBZXSN3LGTLOBQCVGIM1SN4QAO0QTCSM1',
            near: 'xxxxxx',
            intent: 'browse',
            radius: '15000',
            query: 'pizza',
            v: '20170801',
            limit: 1
          }
    };

    request(paramOptions, function(err, res, body) {
         if(err) {
           console.log(err)
         } else {
           res.render('pages/search'); //THIS WILL NOT WORK
           console.log(body) // RETURNS DATA FROM API ENDPOINT

        }
    });
    res.render('pages/search'); // THIS WILL WORK
});
```

The `res.render()` that does work is outside of the scope of the Request function, so I can not access the returned data from this Request function. When I `console.log` the body of the Request function, I do get JSON data returned in my terminal view, so I know Request is working, but I am unsure of how to pass this data into an EJS template as I did with my `fetch()` example.

Comment: Why, in your second example, are you not passing a second parameter to `res.render(filename, data)` that contains the data from your request that you want to go into the rendered page?

Comment: There are two `res` on the scope chain.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate `res` parameters and the inner one is hiding the outer one.  Change the name of the one in this line:

```
request(paramOptions, function(err, res, body) {
```

to something else like this:

```
request(paramOptions, function(err, response, body) {
```

And, then when you call `res.render()`, it will use the higher scoped one you want.

You probably also need to pass some data to `res.render(filename, data)` as the second argument so you can feed the results of the `request()` to your render operation.

And, in your `if (err)` condition, you should send an error status, perhaps `res.sendStatus(500)`.